# Metaprogramming errors in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Alright, so this is driving me crazy. The point of this code is that I ought to be able to add a method dynamically provided it is of the form object.plusnum, where num is any number. I'm not quite sure how to get this to work. This is my best shot at it so far, but I'm currently getting several errors.

Code:

```
class Adder
def initialize(_val)
    @start_value = _val
end

def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    method = method_name.to_s
    if method.start_with?("plus") then
        num = method[4 .. method.length]
        if (/^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/ === num) then
            number = Integer(num)
            self.class_eval("def #{method} return @start_value + #{number} end")
        else
            super
        end
    else
        super
    end
end

end
```

The error I'm currently getting is that "class_eval" is undefined. I am pretty new to metaprogramming and ruby, and this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got it all wrong :)

Calling a method for the first time yields different result, than calling it second time so probably you would like this method to be called instantly after defining. Also -- you are using fairly complex regex and then converting value to `Integer` and dropping all digits after dot.

You are using `class_eval` and passing string to it, which is usually bad idea, and block should be used whenever possible, for security and performance reasons.

How I see it could look:

```
class Adder
  def initialize(val)
    @start_value = val
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    if method_name.to_s =~ /^plus(\d+)$/
      self.class.class_eval do
        define_method(method_name) { @start_value + $1.to_i }
      end
      self.send(method_name)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    class Adder
def initialize(_val)
    @start_value = _val
end

def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    method = method_name.to_s
    if method.start_with?("plus") then
        num = method[4 .. method.length]
        if (/^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/ === num) then
            number = Integer(num)
            self.class.class_eval("def #{method}() return @start_value + #{number} end")
            eval(method)
        else
            super
        end
    else
        super
    end
end

end

a = Adder.new(0)
a.plus1
```

Make sure to add eval(method) in the end to call the method otherwise it will return nil for just creating the method. Or you can simple return with return @start_value + #{number}

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to call `class_eval` on the `Adder` class, not on an instance of adder.
2. The string isn't valid Ruby. Put parentheses after `#{method}`.

The new version of the code:

```
class Adder
def initialize(_val)
    @start_value = _val
end

def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    method = method_name.to_s
    if method.start_with?("plus") then
        num = method[4 .. method.length]
        if (/^[\d]+(\.[\d]+){0,1}$/ === num) then
            number = Integer(num)
            self.class.class_eval("def #{method}() return @start_value + #{number} end")
        else
            super
        end
    else
        super
    end
end

end

a = Adder.new(0)
a.plus1
```

Speaking for myself, the way I would have built this method up is just to start off with

```
class Adder
end

Adder.class_eval("def plus1() return 0 + 1 end")
a = Adder.new
a.plus1
```

and then gradually replaced the hard-wired values with configurable values, rather than writing everything at once.